# Lightning Experience Lookup Field not display option "Create new Object"

Tags: lightning-experience, lookup, lookup-filter

I have a question, I have a Lookup Field in Case to Order but when I click on this field the option "Create new Order" is not visible, just give me suggestions but this option "Create new Order" does not appear.

I Add another Lookup field to the case object for example Project__c and if I see the option "Create new Project".
Do you know how I can show this option "Create new Order" in the Lookup field?

My profile has all the permissions for the Order object.

Comment: You question is very confusing, are you referring to "Related List" section for Order in Case details page?